# How to get the status mysql replication via code

Tags: mysql, replication, status

I'm using mysql with cluster, so I have 1 node active (master) and the other node is slave.

In mysql utilities package, I know how to get status for each node using the command below:

```sh
mysqlrpladmin --master=root@localhost:3333 \
-- slaves=root@localhost:3332,root@localhost:3334 health
```

But I need help getting the status of the node via Java code. I think I need to connect to specific node and "ask" the node about this status.

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the slave and send the [`SHOW SLAVE STATUS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-administration-status.html) query.

Comment: So make the query using the Java MySQL connector.

Comment: thanks, i know it, you speak on this:
connection.createStatement().executeQuery("SHOW SLAVE HOSTS") 
) but the result is so low level, i want the summery like the tool give me.
host       | port  | role    | state  | gtid_mode  | health  |
+------------+-------+---------+--------+------------+---------+
| localhost  | 3333  | MASTER  | UP     | ON         | OK

Comment: It doesn't look like there's anything like that, I guess the tool is performing this query and then reformatting the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!
, I hope that I'll find something.